# Is there any way that in Piecewise we have just introduce condition?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, output-formatting

I have the following code:

```
Piecewise[{{Sin[x], 0 <= x <= 1}}]
```

I just want the mathematica consider the sinus condition, i.e `0 <= x <= 1`. But in output I have:

```
Piecewise[{{Sin[x], 0 <= x <= 1}}, 0]
```

My attempt was as follows:

```
DeleteCases[Piecewise[{{Sin[x], 0 <= x <= 1}}, 0], 0]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the following work for you:

```
Piecewise[{{Sin[x], 0 <= x <= 1}}, Undefined]
```

> ConditionalExpression[Sin[x], 0 <= x <= 1]

Comment: I need output without   `ConditionalExpression`.

Comment: @BahramAgheli no problem if you define `f[x_]:=Piecewise[{{Sin[x], 0 <= x <= 1}}, Undefined]`

Comment: @BahramAgheli What's wrong with `ConditionalExpression` in the ouput?

Comment: @Carl I have the following message for a part of my code `Solve::naqs: Undefined is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities.`

Comment: @BahramAgheli I think you should explain more about your problem, as there's no way we can help when just given an error message and not the input you tried.

Comment: @Carl I think when in a part of my code I have `SOL = Solve[
  Table[F[L, i] == 0, {L, 0, 1}], {y[0, i + 1], y[1, i + 1]}]; SOL /. 
 Rule -> SetDelayed;` in the output, I have an error message.

Comment: @BahramAgheli It would improve your chances at getting a helpful response if you put enough code in your question so that other people can duplicate your issues with the using Piecewise with a default of 0. As it is, there's not enough information here for anybody to give you an answer.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to define a function with the required range (rather than using Piecewise). For example:

```
sin[x_] := If[0 <= x <= 1, Sin[x]];
```

Now sin[0.9] returns a value whereas sin[1.9] is undefined.

Comment: Or `sin[x_] := Sin[x] /; 0 <= x <= 1`

Comment: Many thanks, but I have to use of `Piecewise`.

Comment: Otherwise, how can I derivative of `If[0 <= x <= 1, Sin[x]]`?

Comment: Did you try it? If you take D[sin[x], x] then you get, as you might hope, If[0 <= x <= 1, Cos[x]].

Comment: In my past code I had `Piecewise` and I use of `D` for derivative. Now with new code I have ` u1[x_]:=If[0 <= x <= 1, Sin[x]]`. I have to get derivative of this code. After calculation in my code I have to gain derivative of `u1`.

Comment: For example `D[u1[x]]`

Comment: So how about: D[u1[x],x]